# What is assigned to each mouse button in Pygame.mousebuttondown?

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard, mouse

I'm trying to make a game, and so far I have one button on the title screen. However, I do not know which values are assigned to each button. Please respond with a full list of mousebuttondown buttons assigned to mouse buttons, so I'm not going to have to ask again

Comment: Please see: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed

Comment: it doesn't tell you which buttons are assigned to which (like left/right click)

Comment: There is no *rule* about which button is which. This is not a PyGame thing, but a Mouse thing.  The typical convention is that `1` is left, `2` is right, `3` is middle-mouse (or scroll-wheel click (not scroll)).  But imagine something like a 5-button mouse, or a tap on a touch-screen, or tap on a laptop touch pad, or double-tap, or multi-finger touches.  You can't pre-define how all these current and up-coming technologies will resolve when considered as a mouse click.  It's hardware dependant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation is difficult to understand or incomplete or opaque, you can always inspect yourself.

Here's a minimal example that you can use to print the [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) that are generated with each mouse button press:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Mouse Button Test")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

When you click in the screen, your console will show the event details. E.g., for left click, right-click, middle click, scroll up, scroll down I saw the following:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
<Event(1025-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (131, 134), 'button': 1, 'touch': False, 'window': None})>
<Event(1025-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (131, 134), 'button': 3, 'touch': False, 'window': None})>
<Event(1025-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (131, 134), 'button': 2, 'touch': False, 'window': None})>
<Event(1025-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (131, 134), 'button': 4, 'touch': False, 'window': None})>
<Event(1025-MouseButtonDown {'pos': (131, 134), 'button': 5, 'touch': False, 'window': None})>
```